# Getting VRF to work (and some other questions)

Tags: bgp, mpls, vrf

I'm messing with BGP/MPLS for the first time and I have some doubts both in if I'm doing something wrong with my configuration and if it is the best approach, hope you guys can clarify me a bit here.

So first of all what I'm trying to do is be able to ping from a customer A branch to another customer A branch in another part of the network. Now considering I'm still pretty bad at this and I feel like I did a frankenstein of commands to get it to work a bit from everywhere it's very possible something is misconfigured or what I'm doing isn't possible.

This is the network:

[image]

(Sorry for the lousy paint)

B_South Configuration:

```
!

!
! Last configuration change at 21:51:05 UTC Thu Jan 7 2021
!
version 15.2
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
!
hostname B_South
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
!
no aaa new-model
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip cef
!
ip vrf ARASAKA-1
 rd 1020:1
 route-target export 1020:1
 route-target import 1020:1
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
no ipv6 cef
!
!
mpls traffic-eng tunnels
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
! 
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 10.10.3.3 255.255.255.255
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.10.2.3 255.255.255.0
 duplex full
 mpls ip
 mpls traffic-eng tunnels
 ip rsvp bandwidth 512 512
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 ip address 10.10.4.1 255.255.255.252
 speed auto
 duplex auto
 mpls traffic-eng tunnels
!
interface FastEthernet1/1
 ip vrf forwarding ARASAKA-1
 ip address 10.10.4.5 255.255.255.252
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
interface FastEthernet2/0
 ip address 200.100.4.1 255.255.255.0
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
interface FastEthernet2/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
router ospf 1
 network 10.10.2.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 network 10.10.3.3 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 200.100.4.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 mpls traffic-eng router-id Loopback0
 mpls traffic-eng area 0
!
router bgp 1020
 bgp router-id 10.10.10.11
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 neighbor 10.10.3.1 remote-as 1020
 neighbor 10.10.3.1 update-source Loopback0
 neighbor 10.10.3.1 next-hop-self
 neighbor 10.10.3.2 remote-as 1020
 neighbor 10.10.3.2 update-source Loopback0
 neighbor 10.10.3.2 next-hop-self
 neighbor 10.10.3.4 remote-as 1020
 neighbor 10.10.3.4 update-source Loopback0
 neighbor 10.10.3.4 next-hop-self
 !
 address-family vpnv4
  neighbor 10.10.3.4 activate
  neighbor 10.10.3.4 send-community both
 exit-address-family
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip route 193.136.1.0 255.255.255.192 10.10.4.6
ip route 193.136.1.64 255.255.255.192 10.10.4.6
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 stopbits 1
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
end
```

Arasaka_S configuration:

```
!
!
!

!
! Last configuration change at 09:24:06 UTC Sun Jan 3 2021
!
version 15.2
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
!
hostname Arasaka_S
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
!
no aaa new-model
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip cef
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
no ipv6 cef
!
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
! 
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.10.4.6 255.255.255.252
 duplex full
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 ip address 193.136.1.65 255.255.255.192
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
interface FastEthernet1/1
 ip address 193.136.1.1 255.255.255.192
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
interface FastEthernet2/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
interface FastEthernet2/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
router ospf 1
 network 193.136.1.0 0.0.0.63 area 0
 network 193.136.1.64 0.0.0.63 area 0
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.10.4.5
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 stopbits 1
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
end
```

Arasaka_N configuration:

```
!
!
!

!
! Last configuration change at 08:54:37 UTC Sun Jan 3 2021
!
version 15.2
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
!
hostname Arasaka_N
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
!
no aaa new-model
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip cef
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
no ipv6 cef
!
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
! 
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.10.4.10 255.255.255.252
 duplex full
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 ip address 193.136.1.129 255.255.255.192
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
interface FastEthernet1/1
 ip address 193.136.1.193 255.255.255.192
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
interface FastEthernet2/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
interface FastEthernet2/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
router ospf 1
 network 193.136.1.128 0.0.0.63 area 0
 network 193.136.1.192 0.0.0.63 area 0
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.10.4.9
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 stopbits 1
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
end
```

B_North configuration:

```
!

!
! Last configuration change at 21:57:40 UTC Thu Jan 7 2021
!
version 15.2
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
!
hostname B_North
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
!
no aaa new-model
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip cef
!
ip vrf ARASAKA-1
 rd 1020:1
 route-target export 1020:1
 route-target import 1020:1
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
no ipv6 cef
!
!
mpls traffic-eng tunnels
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
! 
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 10.10.3.4 255.255.255.255
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.10.2.4 255.255.255.0
 duplex full
 mpls ip
 mpls traffic-eng tunnels
 ip rsvp bandwidth 512 512
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 ip vrf forwarding ARASAKA-1
 ip address 10.10.4.9 255.255.255.252
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
interface FastEthernet1/1
 ip address 200.100.2.1 255.255.255.0
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
interface FastEthernet2/0
 ip address 10.20.1.1 255.255.255.0
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
interface FastEthernet2/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
router ospf 1
 network 10.10.2.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 network 10.10.3.4 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 200.100.2.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 mpls traffic-eng router-id Loopback0
 mpls traffic-eng area 0
!
router bgp 1020
 bgp router-id 10.10.10.10
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 neighbor 10.10.3.1 remote-as 1020
 neighbor 10.10.3.1 update-source Loopback0
 neighbor 10.10.3.1 next-hop-self
 neighbor 10.10.3.2 remote-as 1020
 neighbor 10.10.3.2 update-source Loopback0
 neighbor 10.10.3.2 next-hop-self
 neighbor 10.10.3.3 remote-as 1020
 neighbor 10.10.3.3 update-source Loopback0
 neighbor 10.10.3.3 next-hop-self
 !
 address-family vpnv4
  neighbor 10.10.3.3 activate
  neighbor 10.10.3.3 send-community both
 exit-address-family
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip route 193.136.1.128 255.255.255.192 10.10.4.10
ip route 193.136.1.192 255.255.255.192 10.10.4.10
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 stopbits 1
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
end
```

So my questions are:

1-> Why can't router B_south "ping vrf" the B_North vrf interface (f1/0)?

2-> I have added both mpls LDP and mpls RSVP-TE, do I need to use one over the other?

3-> Is having BGP on B_South and B_North a good choice considering BGP as far as I know is more used in
between things like ISP's and not in the same ASs or should I use ospf without VRF to get connectivity between the two?

If I did something horrible wrong here let me know haha.